# Запятая после "Однако"

Tags: пунктуация

Недавно писал документацию к своему продукту, смутил момент с постановкой запятой после слова "однако". Правильно ли поставил запятые в предложениях?

> Однако, наименование и цена удаленного канцтовара доступны в списке заявок сотрудников.
>
> Однако только менеджер имеет возможность просматривать все заявки, включенные в заказы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У слова "однако" три грамматических роли: вводное слово, союз, междометие, при этом обособляются вводное слово и междометие. В приведенных примерах это союз со значением "НО", поэтому запятая не нужна. Примеры с обособлением:Надо, однако, сказать несколько слов о самом герое.Но, однако, я попросил бы вас перейти к сути дела. Это вводные слова, они не встречаются в начале предложения. Однако, какой ветер! Триста тысяч, однако. Это междометия.

Comment: Спасибо :)